# MySQL check if result is favourited

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query that show results for a search and I want to add one more field that checks if each result appears as a favourited result in another table. To keep it simple, as most of the search parameters only add some JOIN and WHERE and are not important to my question, let's consider there is a `results` table that has all the right fields:

```
id | title | description
```

And the result_favourites table:

```
userid | resultid
```

Here is the MySQL query to get results (once again without all the search criterias for simplicity):

```
SELECT id, title, description FROM results
```

What I want is something like that (let's say the user is #1):

```
SELECT r.id r.title, r.description, (something here) AS is_favourited
FROM results AS r
RIGHT JOIN result_favourites AS rf ON rf.resultid = r.id
WHERE userid = 1
```

With is_favourited being either 1 (there is at least one row in result_favourites with both userid and resultid matching r.id and userid = 1) or 0 (there is none).

I've tried to use `COUNT(rf.userid) AS is_favourited` but that didn't work. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `left join`, not `right join`.  A `left join` keeps all rows from the first table.  Then just check if there is a match:

```
SELECT r.id r.title, r.description, (rf.resultid is not null) AS is_favourited
FROM results r LEFT JOIN
     result_favourite rf
     ON rf.resultid = r.id and
        rf.userid = 1;
```

Comment: Perfect, that works! I had tried both LEFT and RIGHT but what made the difference was moving userid =1 from WHERE to the ON clause. For some reason using it in where returns 0 result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT r.id r.title, r.description, if(rf.userid is null,0,1) AS is_favourited
FROM results AS r
left JOIN result_favourites AS rf ON (rf.resultid = r.id)
WHERE userid = 1
```

Comment: Thanks - although I've accepted Gordon's answer because it only works when userid = 1 is in ON, not WHERE (not sure why)